# Whtmltopdf pdf generation

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

We are using wkhtml2pdf for generating pdf it working fine for vertical orientation now my client required vertical orientation please reffer image so I can understand easily.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `--orientation "Landscape"` option when calling `wkhhtmltopdf`.

e.g. from my local install I would run `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --orientation landscape http://google.com google.pdf`

You may need to tweak your top or bottom margins. You can do this by passing `--margin-bottom 1` and `--margin-top 1`. You will need to play around with the values.

For more info you can find the documentation here http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: Yes I did it but it not getting proper spacing.

Comment: @RizwanSultan spacing where? As in margins or borders.

Comment: Orientation working fine now but getting spacing issues on top and bottom area.